# javaCC Count of number of call Function in put file stream

Tags: javacc

I wish that the parser generated by javacc counts the number of calls MyFunction by a statement of program.

my question how I can counter the number of calls of the function MyFunction by other statement in put file stream.

MyFunction is defined by the following JavaCC Rule:

```
  void  MyFunction () {}
    {
    <method> <id> "(" Argument () ")" {}
    (Statement ()) *
    <end_method>
    }

   void  Argument  () {}
    {
    <STRING> id
    <STRING> id
    }

    void statement () {}
    {
    CallMyFonction ()
    statementType2 () // here is another statement that can call method // by CallMyFonction ()
    ...........
    }


   void  CallMyFunction  () {}
    {
    <id> "(" (
         ExpressionTreeStructure ()
         (
           "," ExpressionTreeStructure ()
         ) *
       ) *
    ")"
    }

  void  ExpressionTreeStructure  () {}
    {
    ......
    }
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether you want to count declarations or calls. And, if you want to count calls, do you want separate counts for each function.

(a) **You want to count declarations.** Add an int field "declCount" to the parser class. (Make it static if the parser is static.)  Add a line to MyFunction

```
  void  MyFunction () {}
    {
        <method> <id> "(" Argument () ")" {}
        (Statement ()) *
        <end_method>
        { ++declCount ; } // add this line
    }
```

(b) **You want to count calls.** Add an int field to the parser class called "callCount". (Make it static if the parser is static.) Add a line to CallMyFunction

```
  void  CallMyFunction  () {}
  {
    <id> "(" (
         ExpressionTreeStructure ()
         (
           "," ExpressionTreeStructure ()
         ) *
       ) *
    ")"
    { ++callCount ; } // add this line.
  }
```

(c) **You want to break the call count down by function name.** Add a field to the parser

```
HashMap<String,Integer> callCounts = new HashMap<String,Integer>() ;
```

(Make it static if the parser is static.) Modify `CallMyFunction`

```
    void  CallMyFunction  () {
        Token name ; // Add this line
    }
    {
      name = <id> "(" (
         ExpressionTreeStructure ()
         (
           "," ExpressionTreeStructure ()
         ) *
       ) *
      ")"
      { // Add this block.
        int count = callCounts.containsKey( name.image )
                       ? callCounts.get( name.image )
                       : 0 ;
        callCounts.put( name.image, count + 1 ) ;
      }
}
```

Comment: Hello Professor Theodore Norvell, I coded that you have proposed me as a solution.
it works well.
Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: If an answer answers your question, it is customary to mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the check-mark. This marks it as useful for other users.

Comment: Once , I break the call count down by function name "case  C" above.  I want to records the name of the method called and calling. Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: One way, if you are using JJTree, is to use a visitor that keeps track of what the current function is.  It you want to do it during the parsing pass, then you can add a string parameter to nonterminals such as Statement, and CallMyFunction that contains the name of the current method. Then in MyFunction you'd have `<method> tk=<id> "(" Argument () ")" {} (Statement (tk.image)) * ...`

Comment: I want to do it during the parsing pas, So this `Statement (tk.image)` not accepted , it 'is make one Error. Can you explain me plus. Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: Did you add a string parameter to the `Statement` nonterminal?

Comment: I add a string parameter like `void statement () {String nameOfCall}
    {
    CallMyFonction ()
    statementType2 ()
    ...........
    }`

Comment: Then in MyFunction  `<method> tk=<id> "(" Argument () ")" {} (Statement (tk.image)) *  ....` but i have error message like this The method Statement() in the type MyParseur is not applicable for the arguments (String).   Can you explain me plus. Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: question : is what I have to add a parameter in string  in `CallMyFunction() `  nonterminal?  Thank you in advance

Comment: For your information : `void statement () {}
    {
    CallMyFonction ()
    statementType2 () // here is another statement that can call method // by CallMyFonction ()
    ...........
    }`.     `statementType2 () ` that can call method by `CallMyFonction ()`   Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What I mean is change the declaration of `Statement` to `void Statement(String callerName)() : {} { CallMyFunction(callerName) | ... }` similarly with `CallMyFunction` and any other nonterminals that need it. Then at the point of call you have both the name of the calling function and the name of the called function.

Comment: Hello Mister Theodore Norvell.  It is Good. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem. Since this is related to your education, be sure to cite the relevant stackoverflow questions in your report.